# Cordova choose video resulting path without extension

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using below code to select a video from library

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (data) {
    callback(true, data);
},
function (e) {
    callback(false, null);
}, {
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.VIDEO
});
```

But in callback I am getting path in below format

```
 content://media/external/video/media/832
```

How can I get the original file path?

Answer (score 0):

I know its to late but maybe someone else needs this ( use resolveLocalFileSystemURL then toURL() ) 
check this code

```
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
                limit: 1,
                mediaType: window.Camera.MediaType.VIDEO,
                destinationType: window.Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            });

            function onSuccess(fileURI) {

                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI,
   function (fileEntry) {
       console.log(fileEntry.toURL());
       //console.log(fileEntry.fullPath);
   },
   function () { });
            }
            function onFail(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

step1
cordova plugin add cordova-filepath-resolver

For Ionic specifically, you can also use:

ionic plugin add cordova-filepath-resolver

step2

put this code

```
 function camerasucess(videourl) {
            //videourl is something like this    content //media/external/video
            var successCallback = function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                //here you will get the correct path of the video file and you can upload the video file
                $scope.data = data;
            };
            var errorCallback = function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            };


            window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(videourl, successCallback, errorCallback);


        };
        function cameraError(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        };

        if (navigator.camera)
        {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(camerasucess, cameraError, {
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.VIDEO,
            });

        }
```